# Test case not getting exception thrown by method under test

Tags: mockito, scalatest

This is my method under test. I want to test that if it receives an exception, it processes it (if needed) and throws it further.

```
def handleNewUserTransaction(profile:UserProfile) = Future{ 
    logger.trace(s"handling new user transaction with profile ${profile}")
    val (userKeys,user,emailToken) = getParametersTohandleNewUserTransaction(profile)
    logger.trace(s"handing new user transaction with values ${userKeys},${user},${emailToken}")
    try{
      userTransactionDatabaseService.handleNewUserDatabaseTransaction(userKeys,user,emailToken)
      sendEmailUsingConfirmationToken(user,emailToken)
      //checktest-user is added on success
      true
    } catch {
      case exception:UserNotConfirmedException => {
        //checktest-email is sent for unconfirmed user
        logger.trace(s"user not confirmed. Will resent email")
        sendEmailToUnconfirmedUser(emailToken,exception.user)
        throw exception
      }
        //checktest-throw exception if error
      case exception:Throwable => {
        logger.trace(s"got exception ${exception}")
        throw exception
      }
    }
  }
```

I am simulating an exception scenario via this test case

```
"throw exception if error" in {
      val servicesTestEnv = new ServicesTestEnv(components=components)
      //val exception = UnconfirmedUserException().asInstanceOf[RuntimeException]
      val userTransactionService = new UserTransactionService(servicesTestEnv.userTestEnv.mockMailerService,components.configuration,servicesTestEnv.mockUserTransactionDBService,servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods)
      when(servicesTestEnv.mockUserTransactionDBService.handleNewUserDatabaseTransaction(ArgumentMatchers.any[UserKeys],ArgumentMatchers.any[User],ArgumentMatchers.any[UserToken]))
        .thenAnswer(invocation => {throw UserDoesNotExistException()})
      when(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods.generateUserKeysFromEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any[String]))
        .thenReturn(servicesTestEnv.userTestEnv.userKeys)
      when(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods.hashPassword(ArgumentMatchers.any[String]))
        .thenReturn(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.passwordInfo)
      when(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods.bucketIDFromEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any[String]))
        .thenReturn(1)
      when(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID())
        .thenReturn(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.user.id)
      when(servicesTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods.generateEmailTokenForUser(ArgumentMatchers.any[User], ArgumentMatchers.any[UserTokenType.TokenType]))
        .thenReturn(servicesTestEnv.userTestEnv.userToken)
      intercept[UserDoesNotExistException](userTransactionService.handleNewUserTransaction(UserProfile(None,servicesTestEnv.testEnv.externalUserProfile)))
      verify(servicesTestEnv.mockUserTransactionDBService,times(1)).handleNewUserDatabaseTransaction(ArgumentMatchers.any[UserKeys],ArgumentMatchers.any[User],ArgumentMatchers.any[UserToken])
      verify(servicesTestEnv.userTestEnv.mockMailerService,times(0)).sendEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any[String], ArgumentMatchers.any[String],ArgumentMatchers.any[List[String]],ArgumentMatchers.any[Option[String]],ArgumentMatchers.any[Option[String]])

    }
```

But the test case fails with reason - `Expected exception utilities.UserDoesNotExistException to be thrown, but no exception was thrown`

I checked my traces and can see the exception getting thrown by mock - `2020-08-17 08:22:27,461 [TRACE] from services.UserTransactionService in scala-execution-context-global-33 - got exception utilities.UserDoesNotExistException: Invalid user`

Why is the test case failing?

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake. The function was returning a `Future`. The test case wasn't waiting for the `Future` to finish.

```
val exception = intercept[UserDoesNotExistException](await[Boolean](userTransactionService.handleNewUserTransaction(UserProfile(None,servicesTestEnv.testEnv.externalUserProfile)))(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))))
```